# Django + APP ENGINE (GAE) - No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-secret-manager, secret-manager

i want to deploy in App Engine a Django app.
I created and configurate a SECRET MANAGER in GAE and when i want to get that secret from my SETTINGS.PY, it display the error 'No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found'.

If i create the .env locally it works, but i want to get the secret info from the GAE.

**SETTING.PY**

```
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")

if os.path.isfile(env_file):
   # Use a local secret file, if provided

   env.read_env(env_file)
# ...
elif os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", None):
   # Pull secrets from Secret Manager
   project_id = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")

   client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
   settings_name = os.environ.get("SETTINGS_NAME", "secret-django-phi")
   name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{settings_name}/versions/latest"
   payload = client.access_secret_version(name=name).payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

   env.read_env(io.StringIO(payload))
else:
   raise Exception("No local .env or GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT detected. No secrets found.")
```

**REQUIREMENTS.txt**

```
google-cloud-secret-manager==1.0.0
django-environ==0.4.5
```

**SECRET MANAGER that i upload on GAE like an .env file**

```
db_ip=x
db_name=x
db_user=x
db_pass=x
SECRET_KEY=*a lot of characters*
```

Comment: Have you set the environment variable GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT?  Make sure your Python code is getting that correctly.

Comment: Hey, i solved it by setting the environment variable locally. Thabks you

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error, while running locally. Turned out I had my .env in the parent directory, but the example code from Google assumes it's in the current directory. I just changed:

```py
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")
```

to

```py
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../.env")
```

and that fixed my problem.